# this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key ' *** First throw call stack

Tags: iphone, storyboard, key-value, uipagecontrol, uncaught-exception

I am fairly new to creating apps butI have created a UI page control app which works fine. 
I used the following tutorial which was really helpful.

http://www.wannabegeek.com/?p=168

How ever i wanted to add buttons onto each of the child views which would then take me to another view. I have managed to do this and it now goes back and forth between views and back to the scroll.

However now i have added the views for each of the buttons i have no way of being able to control them, ive tried adding new header and implementation classes to the project to be able to control for example the scroll etc and i am getting this error message.

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key twitterFeed.'
*** First throw call stack:

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to your xib and click cntrl+left click and then you will see one connection that have different color. So please remove it and then run you project you will get success. For more info see in this pic

[image]